# Flutter web server only accessible on localhost:8080, how to enable LAN access?

Tags: flutter

I am a novice and I have a question I would like to ask you.

Problem:
flutter web does not allow the same LAN device ip to connect.

Description:
The local computer can connect to the website through 192.168.1.x:8080 or localhost:8080, but it cannot log in to the webpage with another mobile phone connected to the LAN. I have tried Nodejs server, and there is no such problem.

Background environment:
Operating system: IOS
flutter version: 3.7.0

Tried so far:
1. flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname 0.0.0.0 --web-port 8080
2. Firewall off.

I expect him to be able to allow me to access web pages in the same local area network as Nodejs server.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change your localhost name to your IP address:

```
flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname (IP here) --web-port 8080
```

If that doesn't work, try this:
https://medium.com/@TheOlajos/lan-cross-platform-application-using-xampp-and-flutter-markup-language-in-under-10-minutes-1b5151cc7525